# Finding max value in a list of list

Tags: python, datetime, max, grouping

I am looking for an elegant way to take a list of lists and find the max value for a subset of elements. It is better explained with a small example. Given the following input:

```
data = [['1','AAA','somestuff','1/5/2018'],
        ['1','AAA','differentstuff','1/5/2018'],
        ['1','AAA','evendifferent','1/10/2018'],
        ['2','BBB','foo','1/12/2018'],
        ['2','BBB','bar','1/20/2018']]
```

I would like to return the following list of lists:

```
[['1','AAA','evendifferent','1/10/2018'], 
    ['2','BBB','bar','1/20/2018']]
```

Output is grouped by index 1 of inner lists and maximum value is based on the date (last item in inner list).

Comment: Max based on what criteria?  I assume you don't just want whatever python's sort does to strings.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get a datetime from your string-date - else `'1/5/2018'` compares "bigger" then `'1/10/2018'` because `'5' > '1'` for strings.

You can achieve this like so:

```
data = [['1','AAA','somestuff','1/5/2018'],
        ['1','AAA','differentstuff','1/5/2018'] ,
        ['1','AAA','evendifferent','1/10/2018'] ,
        ['2','BBB','foo','1/12/2018'] ,
        ['2','BBB','bar','1/20/2018']]


# group by AAA, BBB etc. into lists 
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    dd[d[1]].append(d)

import datetime

# iterate over groups and get the maximum value of each list
for k in dd:
    # for the datetime converted da
    print(max ( dd[k], key = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[-1],"%d/%M/%Y")))
```

Documentation:

- [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [max using key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: Thank you. That got me going in the right direction and it worked out in my specific case.